# How to replace if else statement with switch statement

Tags: java, android

Hi I am in a situation where I need to use multiple `else if's` and I would like to use `switch` statements, I have tried a lot but I am not able to do so. How can I convert the following else if's to switch?

```
public ApiObservables(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof SitesController) {
            mSitesApi = getSitesApi();
        } else if (o instanceof QuestionController) {
            mQuestionApi = getQuestionApi();
        } //more else if's
    }
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
public ApiObservables(Object o) {
        switch (o) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Usually it's better to use polymorphic method calls instead of `instanceof` checks, even if it could be done with a switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

- When using switch case, the **control variable** must be of **primitive type**, or String, or enum. You cannot use objects in switch-case.
  From JLS:

  > The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type
- The switch case only checks for equality ( i.e., similar to using == operator). So, you cannot use `instanceof` in switch-case

Comment: So do you mean that it is not possible to use switch in this case?

Comment: @NonthonbamTonthoi  Yes.

Comment: You can switch Enums too

Comment: @Guy Yes. Just checked the JLS

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, I would use method overloading :

```
public ApiObservables foo(Object o) {
  //throw new IllegalArgumentException?
}

public ApiObservables foo(SitesController o) {
  return getSitesApi();
}

public ApiObservables foo(QuestionController o) {
  return getQuestionApi();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

I don't  know if you can refactor your code but What about a diffetent approach using interfaces? Something like this:

```
interface API {
   //method signatures here
}

class SitesApi implements API {
    //implementation here
}

class QuestionApi implements API {
    //implementation here
}

interface Controller {
    API getAPI();
}

class QuestionController implements Controller {
    @Override
    public API getAPI() {
        return new QuestionAPI();
    }
}

class SitesController implements Controller {
    @Override
    public API getAPI() {
        return new SitesAPI();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public ApiObservables(Controller controller) {
    someApi = controller.getAPI();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    I don't know about your remaining code try this by passing in this function repective controller string as per your object

    and if you use object in switch case then i think it will not support

try this one

        public ApiObservables(String o) {
            switch(o) {
            case "SitesController":
               mSitesApi = getSitesApi();
               break;

             case "QuestionController":
            mQuestionApi = getQuestionApi();

             default:
               System.out.println("place any thing that you want to show any message");
               break;
            }
        }
```